# Package accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, java-11

I was trying to switch my project from java8 to java11. While switching I am facing the below errors:

1. Package accessible from more than one modules.
2. cannot be resolved to a type/variable. (Here  is an dependent library)

I was looking forward for solution to resolve this. It will be helpful if I got any working example to understand better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A package must be defined in one and only one module.  You may not define classes in the same package in different modules.

Comment: @VGR - actually i have different 3rd party library where they have "java.net" package. In java11, "java.net" package is already available in "java.base". I need to upgrade my application from java8 to java11. In java11, I am getting "package accessible from more than one modules". I was looking out for a steps to make those different package from different jar to act as a same module. Like using --patch-module.

Comment: I cannot think of any valid reason for a third party library to include java.net classes.  I would first look for a version of that library which does not include them.  If no such version exists, I would have my build process strip them from that library.  The good news is, the error you’re encountering is exactly what should happen;  no library should be able to sneak its own hacks into the Java SE runtime used by a program.